# How to change dynamic object query to criteria builder or better performence

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate-criteria

Hello I wrote a join query but I do not have a relational annotations on my entities. I like to change my query for a better performance. Is there any other way to do it

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> search(String code, String name, String username, String shopName, String startDate, String endDate) {
    Query query = null;
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(" AND ");
    stringJoiner.add("SELECT sthLogin.sthId, sth.sthMobileNumber, sth.createdDate, sth.expiryDate, sth.brandingName, sth.shopName" +
            " FROM tbl_sth_login_credentials sth INNER JOIN tbl_maintain_sth_profile sth ON sth.Id = sth.sthPrimaryId WHERE sth.deletionStatus = 'N' ");

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sthCode))
        stringJoiner.add("stlogin.code = '" + sthCode + "'");

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sthName))
        stringJoiner.add("sth.brandingName = '" + sthName + "'");

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(username))
        stringJoiner.add("sthLogin.sthMobileNumber = '" + username + "'");

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(shopName))
        stringJoiner.add("sth.shopName = '" + shopName + "'");


    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(shopName) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(endDate))
        stringJoiner.add("sth.createdDate BETWEEN '" + startDate + "' AND '" + endDate + "' ");

    query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(stringJoiner.toString());
    return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Execute it in a sql-editor and run an explain plan on your query (depends on your database how to do that), then see which parts are taking long and start to optimize that (like adding appropriate indexes), it's hard to see what's going slow or how to improve performance from this alone.

Comment: Actually I like to change my code according to criteria builder. But as I mention on my topic I have no mapping annotations. How can ı do that. Thank you for reply

Comment: Don't operate on SQL using string builders, what if ShopName will contain weird characters? Look at PreparedStatement API